# Why is my loss negative sometines when I use WGAN?

Tags: deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

When I use WGAN,sometimes loss is negative??
mo loss code:

```
self.g_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(d_logits_fake)
self.d_loss = tf.reduce_mean(d_logits_fake) - tf.reduce_mean(d_logits_real)+GP
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that calcualting g_loss and d_loss need use `Model.train_on_batch`.I don't know what `d_logits_fake` comes from.

Comment: I'm newer to wgan. If you have opposite or creative suggestions, please contact me.